# If [x,z] and [y,z] commute for all x,y,z in R, then $[x,y]^4=0$ for all x,y in R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $\bigl[x,\, z\bigr]$ and $\bigl[y,\, z\bigr]$ commute for all $x,\, y,\, z\in R$, then  $\bigl[x,\, y\bigr]^{4}=0$ for all $x,\, y\in R$. In such a ring $R$ a commutator $c$ satisfy the equation of the form $c^{n}=c$ for some $n>1$, if only if $c=0$

I have a proof of this theorem. However I don't understad one thing in this proof.

Suppose $c=\bigl[x,\, y\bigr]$ for some $x,\, y\in R$. Note that $cx=(xy-yx)x=xyx-yx^{2}=\bigl[x,\, yx\bigr]=\bigl[-yx,\, x\bigr]$ and $c=\bigl[-y,\, x\bigr]$ so $c$ and $cx$ commute. Thus $xc^{2}=cxc$ and similarly $yc^{2}=cyc$. Since 
 $yc=\bigl[yx,\, y\bigr]=\bigl[-y,\, yx\bigr]$, $cx$ and  $yc$ commute as well. Thus

$(cx)(yc)c=(yc^{2})xc=cy(cxc)=cyxc^{2}$

My problem starts now how to show from this equation above that $c^4=0$.

Comment: Ok: what are the assumptions (i.e., what is given), and what has to be proved? I just can't understand....and apparently we're talking about *a ring* $\;R\;$ , right? Unitary...? There's need to be way clearer.

Comment: @DonAntonio: http://archive.maths.nuim.ie/staff/sbuckley/Papers/bm_variations.pdf Theorem 19

Comment: I just have problem with understanding this proof.

Comment: My problems with that proof begin much sooner (I haven't read that paper though): where it says "so by assumption $\,c\;,\;\;cx\;$ commute? What "assumption" in the theorem's wording allows us to deduce this?!

Answer (score 1):

As the linked paper says, subtract the far right from the far left of the chain of equalities:

$$ 0 = (cx)(yc)c - cyxc^2 \\= c(xy)c^2 - c(yx)c^2 \\ = c(xy-yx)c^2 \\ = c[x,y]c^2 = c^4 $$

Comment: @ Anthony Carapetis: Thank you for your answer. It really helped. It seems so easy now. Could you help me with the next part of the proof. 
Since $3n-2\geq4$ we deduce that $c^{3n-2}=0$. I can't understand this as well.